# How do I get multiple MockFor working in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, junit, mocking

I am trying to get multiple mocks working in groovy. The only way I have managed to get this working is to create my own kind of mock - adding a meta method.

I have tried using nested use statements and also tried one use and one proxy with verify, neither of which worked. Both of these returned a failure - "junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No more calls to 'pop' expected at this point. End of demands."

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import org.junit.Test

class MockTest {
    // results in No more calls to 'pop' expected at this point. End of demands.
    @Test
    public void testMock() {
        MockFor pupilMock = new MockFor(Pupil)
        MockFor bubbleMock = new MockFor(SomeService)
        GroovyObject bubbleProxy = bubbleMock.proxyInstance()
        pupilMock.demand.blowBubble { String colour ->
            return bubbleProxy
        }
        bubbleMock.demand.pop {}
        pupilMock.use {
            bubbleMock.use {
                Teacher teacher = new Teacher()
                teacher.lesson("red")
            }
        }
    }
    // results in No more calls to 'pop' expected at this point. End of demands.
    @Test
    public void testProxy() {
        MockFor pupilMock = new MockFor(Pupil)
        MockFor bubbleMock = new MockFor(SomeService)
        GroovyObject bubbleProxy = bubbleMock.proxyInstance()
        pupilMock.demand.blowBubble { String colour ->
            return bubbleProxy
        }
        bubbleMock.demand.pop {}
        pupilMock.use {
                Teacher teacher = new Teacher()
                teacher.lesson("red")
        }
        bubbleMock.verify(bubbleProxy)
    }
    // only using a single mock so works
    @Test
    public void testMetaclass() {
        MockFor pupilMock = new MockFor(Pupil)
        SomeService.metaClass.pop = { println "pop was called" }
        SomeService metaBubble = new SomeService("red")
        pupilMock.demand.blowBubble { String colour ->
            return metaBubble
        }
        pupilMock.use {
                Teacher teacher = new Teacher()
                teacher.lesson("red")
        }
    }
}

class Teacher {
    public void lesson(String colour) {
        Pupil pupil = new Pupil()
        SomeService bubble = pupil.blowBubble(colour)
        bubble.pop()
    }
}

class Pupil {
    SomeService blowBubble(String colour) {
        SomeService child = new SomeService(colour)
        return child
    }
}

class SomeService {
    String colour

    SomeService(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour
    }
    void pop() {
        println "popped ${colour}"
    }
}
```

EDIT: Re comment about mocking something constructed and returned from a method, this is how I do it...

```
@Test
public void testMockReturned() {
    MockFor bubbleMock = new MockFor(SomeService)
    bubbleMock.demand.pop {}
    bubbleMock.use {
        Pupil pupil = new Pupil()
        SomeService service = pupil.blowBubble("red")
        service.pop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `Pupil` should be a stub since you're only using it to inject `bubbleProxy` to you can perform verification against it. Like this,

```
    import groovy.mock.interceptor.*
    import org.junit.Test

    class MockTest {
        @Test
        public void testMock() {
            StubFor pupilMock = new StubFor(Pupil)
            MockFor bubbleMock = new MockFor(SomeService)
            GroovyObject bubbleProxy = bubbleMock.proxyInstance()
            pupilMock.demand.blowBubble { String colour ->
                return bubbleProxy
            }
            bubbleMock.demand.pop {}
            bubbleMock.use {
                Teacher teacher = new Teacher()
                teacher.lesson("red")
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I believe the demands are copied onto the proxy when `proxyInstance()` is called, so you need to have your demands configured before instantiating the proxy.
However, I don't think there's a problem with multiple mocks, I think you just can't mix instance and class mocks (which you are doing with `SomeService`). The smallest example I could think of that demonstrates this was

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor

// this works
missyMock = new MockFor(Missy)
missyMock.demand.saySomethingNice {}
missy = missyMock.proxyInstance()
missy.saySomethingNice()
missyMock.verify(missy)

// as does this
missyMock = new MockFor(Missy)
missyMock.demand.saySomethingNice {}
missyMock.use {
    new Missy().saySomethingNice()
}

// this don't
missyMock = new MockFor(Missy)
missyMock.demand.saySomethingNice {}
missy = missyMock.proxyInstance()
missyMock.use {  // fails here in use()'s built-in verify()
    missy.saySomethingNice()
}
missyMock.verify(missy)

class Missy {
    void saySomethingNice() {}
}
```

To demonstrate that the multiple mocks with nested `use` closures works, look at this contrived example

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import org.junit.Test

class MockTest {
    @Test
    public void testMock() {
        MockFor lessonMock = new MockFor(Lesson)
        MockFor pupilMock = new MockFor(Pupil)
        lessonMock.demand.getLessonPlan {}
        pupilMock.demand.getName {}

        pupilMock.use {
            lessonMock.use {
                Teacher teacher = new Teacher()
                Pupil pupil = new Pupil()
                Lesson lesson = new Lesson()
                teacher.teach(pupil, lesson)
            }
        }
    }
}

class Teacher {
    void teach(Pupil pupil, Lesson lesson) {
        println "Taught ${pupil.getName()} $lesson by ${lesson.getLessonPlan()}"
    }
}

class Pupil {
    String name
}

class Lesson {
    LessonPlan lessonPlan

    static class LessonPlan {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll keep that in mind. The scenario I am using in the non example code looks like it calls for two mocks so would be nice to get that going. The nested style of mocks should work from what I've searched for.

Comment: When I try out your testMock and add a verify call (pupilMock.verify()) I get blowBubble was not called. All looks like it should work, perhaps I have some error in the code that I just can't spot.

Comment: Nope, That's right. Adding a `verify()` call to the `Pupil` object wouldn't work because it's a stub not a mock.

Comment: But actually, I have a goof too... we're still using the real `Pulpil` object in the `lesson()`.  Did you mean for that to be a class field or an arg maybe?  I don't know of a way to mock something that's instantiated in a method.

Comment: I can mock something returned from a method like this   
    @Test
   public void testMockReturned() {
        MockFor bubbleMock = new MockFor(SomeService)
        bubbleMock.demand.pop {}
        bubbleMock.use {
            Pupil pupil = new Pupil()
            SomeService service = pupil.blowBubble("red")
            service.pop()
        }
    }

Comment: You're right... for some reason last night I was thinking of mocking just 1 object, not the entire class.