# Groovy MockFor: How to avoid nested closures when using multiple mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, clean-architecture

I have three classes:

```
class B1 {
    def performB1(){}
}

class B2 {
    def performB2(){}
}

class A {
    private B1 b1
    private B2 b2

    A(b1, b2){
        this.b1 = b1
        this.b2 = b2
    }

    def perfromA(){
        b1.performB1()
        b2.performB2()
    }
}
```

I want to test the method `performA` in the class `A`. So I created mocks for classes `B1` and `B2`. Here is my class:

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor;

 class ATest  extends GroovyTestCase {
     private MockFor b1Mock
     private MockFor b2Mock

    void setUp() {
        b1Mock = new MockFor(B1)
        b2Mock = new MockFor(B2)
    }


    void testIsEnoughSpaceOnArtifactory_failedToGetQuotaFromArtifactory(){
        b1Mock.demand.with {
            performB1 { println "Performing B1" }
        }

        b2Mock.demand.with {
            performB2 {println "Performing B2"}
        }

        b2Mock.use {
           b1Mock.use {
               def a = new A(new B1(), new B2())
               a.perfromA()
           }
        }
    }
}
```

It works well- I verified it. It is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237956/how-do-i-get-multiple-mockfor-working-in-groovy).

However, suppose that I have a class with three dependencies. It is still clean code. It requires 3 mocks. The code would look like that:

```
b3Mock.use { 
    b2Mock.use {
        b1Mock.use {
            def a = new A(new B1(), new B2(), new B3())
            a.perfromA()
        }
    }
}
```

It looks ridiculous and is far from being clean. Imagine that I failed to meet the goal of no more than 3 dependencies. Then my tests will look like even more ridiculous. Is there a way to verify calls on mocks without nested closures? I could use something like that (see [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-testing-guide.html) for reference):

```
b1Mock.use { 
    def a = new A(new B1(), b2Mock.proxyInstance(), b3Mock.proxyInstance())
    a.perfromA()
}
b2Mock.expect.verify()
b3Mock.expect.verify()
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method performB2() on null object

**Is it possible to use multiple mocks in groovy without nested closures to have clean code?**

Comment: Do the classes have to be Mocked? The [docs](http://groovy-lang.org/testing.html#_mockfor_and_stubfor) suggest `StubFor` might suffice for loosely ordered expectations

Comment: @thehole, I need to check the sequence of called methods as well as the number of calls. I believe the classes should be mocked in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following script works fine:

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
//------ CLASSES
class B1 { def performB1(){} }
class B2 { def performB2(){} }
class B3 { def performB3(){} }

class A {
    private B1 b1
    private B2 b2
    private B3 b3

    A(b1, b2, b3){
        this.b1 = b1
        this.b2 = b2
        this.b3 = b3
    }

    def perfromA(){
        b1.performB1()
        b2.performB2()
        b3.performB3()
    }
}
//------ TESTS
def b1Mock = new MockFor(B1)
def b2Mock = new MockFor(B2)
def b3Mock = new MockFor(B3)

b1Mock.demand.with {
    performB1 { println "Performing B1" }
}
b2Mock.demand.with {
    performB2 {println "Performing B2"}
}
b3Mock.demand.with {
    performB3 {println "Performing B3"}
}

def b2inst = b2Mock.proxyInstance()
def b3inst = b3Mock.proxyInstance()
b1Mock.use { 
    def a = new A(new B1(), b2inst, b3inst)
    a.perfromA()
}
b2Mock.verify(b2inst)
b3Mock.verify(b3inst)
```

and with the following function

```
def useAll(List<MockFor> mocks,Closure test){
    Closure use4all = mocks.inject(test){ Closure testX, next-> 
        return { next.use(testX) } 
    }
    use4all.call()
}
```

possible to minimize nested use-closures to this:

```
useAll([b1Mock,b2Mock,b3Mock]){
    def a = new A(new B1(), new B2(), new B3())
    a.perfromA()
}
```